# How to add a signature to all outgoing SMS messages in Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice, sms

How can I make Google Voice attach a signature to all my outgoing SMS messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible yet.

See: 
http://www.google.pl/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=3829239cdefc77dc&hl=en

Suggest it:
http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved using a Greasemonkey script. You can take an existing one from [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org) - start with one that works on Google Voice ([like this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/76882)) and add your signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [Mo+ app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moplus.moplusapp).

Go to your Mo+ setting, click Google Voice, click signature and change it the way you want.

Comment: @Rockpaperlizard This was a pretty marginal edit, but I think the link is better than the giant photo.